# Displaying semi transparent overlay above VideoView or MediaPlayer of Android:

Tags: android, media-player, overlay, android-videoview, alpha

How to display semi transparent overlay above VideoView or MediaPlayer of Android. 
   Currently, in my application alpha value is ignored when displaying over VideoView or MediaPlayer, where as same works when displayed on image view.

Please help me to fix this at earliest.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add another layout (*beside layout that contains your VideoView*) and add transparent background to it.